# curl doesn't verify a certificate with exported site's certificate in Firefox passed by --cacert

Tags: ssl, curl, wget, certificate

I am not much of an expert in SSL, please excuse me if I use some SSL related terms incorrectly. For some reason I can't download a file by https with curl supplying it with this site's certificate with --cacert option.

I have an Intranet site accessible by https. It is possible to open this site in Firefox after accepting a untrusted (or self signed) SSL certificate. I exported this site's certificate from Firefox to a file. The I have removed all certificates from /etc/pki/tls/certs , so curl can't find certificates anywhere besides those in the file supplied by the --cacert option.

When I run curl with --cacert option specifying the certificate file it fails:

```
curl -v https://some-intranet-site.com/repodata/repomd.xml --cacert exported_certificate.cer

* Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

When I export the Google's certificate and try to access https://gogole.com with curl it works:

```
curl https://google.com --cacert ~/dev/tmp/google.cert 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Could you give any explanation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using self-signed certificates is maybe not so good since you get warnings.

In any case, you should make sure the CN of the server certificate contains the server's DNS name. Also, make sure that the exported_certificate.cer is in PEM format. My guess is that your is in DER format. If PEM format then you read it in a regular text editor, if DER it is binary.

Finally, if you don't want to verify the server cert, so you can skip this with curl using "-k". So in your case, "curl -k -v https://some-intranet-site.com/repodata/repomd.xml"